# Empty metadata on pdf obtained from compilation

Tags: hyperref, pdf, metadata

When I compile a .tex file in latex and I get the corresponding .pdf, I can obtain information concerning the file. Thus, for example, I can find out what is the title (which can be set with pdftitle={...}), who is the author (which can be set with pdftitle={...}), etc.

Here there is the question: how can I obtain empty output on all these metadata **with hyperref**?
I am thinking in particular about creation date and modification date, since it seems to me that they produce an output (a date) no matter what.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

---

Here there is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
  pdfcreator={},
  pdftitle={Hello world!},%
  pdfauthor={Somebody},%
  pdfsubject={},%
  pdfproducer={},%
  pdfcreationdate={Bla}%
}

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

If I check the metadata for example with Preview, I get that there is no creation date. Interestingly enough, this is the case if I write something between the relevant brackets (if I leave that empty, then the creation date corresponds to when I actually created the pdf).

Thus, here two questions:

1. why the above described behavior in the creation date option?
2. How to get empty output on modification date as well?

Comment: Indeed, I am sorry. I just realized this while you were writing and I tried to improve my question. The idea is to get the result by using hyperref with pdflatex.

Comment: For example, in the above mentioned setting, I can get empty output regarding the creation date by setting pdfcreationdate={}, but I cannot see how to do it for the modification date.

Comment: I added a MWE example that shows the problem (and the doubts) that I am facing. Really thanks a lot for any feedback!

Comment: Ah. On "Preview" that does not show up (a bit disappointing, really). Ok, so the questions remain: how to get empty output on creation and modification date with hyperref

Comment: you can set the date with eg `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 pdflatex file`  but I'm not sure you can set it to empty

Comment: I see. As a matter of fact, I just found out that, even if it is enough to write \pdfcreationdate={ } to get the output empty on "Preview", if I look at the info in the file, all the data are still there. Hence, this is not really a solution.

Comment: Thus, just to get it right, we have no control over this? (Also, I found out that it is possible to use \pdfinfo{}, but apparently does not work very well with hyperref.

Answer (score 2):

- List item

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
  pdfcreator={},
  pdftitle={Hello world!},%
  pdfauthor={Somebody},%
  pdfsubject={},%
  pdfproducer={},%
  pdfcreationdate={Bla}%
}
\pdfinfoomitdate=1
\begin{document}

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

causes the date info to be omittted:

```
    Title:          Hello world!
    Subject:        
    Keywords:       
    Author:         Somebody
    Creator:        
    Producer:       
    CreationDate:   Bla
    Tagged:         no
    UserProperties: no
    Suspects:       no
    Form:           none
    JavaScript:     no
    Pages:          1
    Encrypted:      no
    Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
    Page rot:       0
    File size:      12994 bytes
    Optimized:      no
    PDF version:    1.5
```